# bootstrap carousel height difference in responsive mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have many carousel sliders in my website 
and it works fine in PC, but when I open the website in mobile devices it gets a little ugly.

Here is the problem:

Let's say in each slide of the carousel I have 4 images maximum and they are in `col-md-3.col-12` div

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" alt="First slide" style="height:20px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" alt="First slide" style="height:20px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" alt="First slide" style="height:20px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" alt="First slide" style="height:20px">
      </div>
    </div>


    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" alt="First slide" style="height:20px">
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

In the first slide/item I have 4 divs , each of them has `20px` height, in mobile view `div.col-12.col-md-4` are positioned vertically and they go under each other, so this slide height is `80px` in total.

In the next slide/item I have 1 `div.col-12.col-md-4` which means this slide is 20px in height.

here is the first slide

[image]

and here is the next slide

[image]

So when slide changes page jumps up and down because of these height differences.

What's the solution to deal with this?

I guess i can add min-height:80px to carousel to compensate for the height loss in different slides (only in mobile view of course ) ... but it wouldn't be very clean

or i can disable carousel  in the mobile view so all the items would be shown without sliding (not sure if possible or how )

here is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3uq4ozd2/1/

Comment: Bootstrap 4 carousel should not place slides one under the other. Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wlarch/Lumyhg18/1/. You can also set a max-height on your carousels to make sure they do not move the viewport/page.

Comment: @wlarcheveque sorry i think i didnt explain the problem properly  , in the mobile view images with changes to 100% so each image would cover entire width of page ... i used col div to show  this problem 

here is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3uq4ozd2/1/

Comment: If this is mobile, then, why don't you make the view, be 100% of the viewport (min-height: 100vh;) and just let there be more space between the images?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you normalize Bootstrap Carousel slide heights so the height can be set to the tallest slide :

```
function normalizeSlideHeights() {
    $('.carousel').each(function(){
      var items = $('.carousel-item', this);

      // reset the height
      items.css('min-height', 0);

      // set the height
      var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, 
          items.map(function(){
              return $(this).outerHeight()}).get() );

      items.css('min-height', maxHeight + 'px');
    })
}

$(window).on('resize orientationchange', normalizeSlideHeights);
```

Reference : 
https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/normalize-bootstrap-carousel-heights